# SQL select medicalExamDate and add a year and end of month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

```
SELECT medicalDate
FROM PilotMedical
WHERE pilotID = '1'
```

This will get the date of the medical exam. However, I need to return when this medical exam expires, which is one year from the date, and the last day of the month. For example, if I get a medical exam on January 12th, 2012, it will expire January 31st, 2013.

medicalDate is a "date" type.

How can I do this in SQL? Basically I want to have it return 1/31/2013 for a medical exam any time in January 2012.

If not, I guess I can do it in VB. I'm much more interested in learning how to do it in VB as I don't plan on working with VB the rest of my life

EDIT:

This will get the last day of the month

```
--Last Day of Any Month and Year
DECLARE @dtDate DATETIME
SET @dtDate = '8/18/2007'
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dtDate)+1,0))
LastDay_AnyMonth

ResultSet:
LastDay_AnyMonth
———————–
2007-08-31 23:59:59.000
```

Now looking for how to add a year to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @OrigDate datetime
DECLARE @NewDate datetime

SET @OrigDate = '1/12/2012'

SET @NewDate = DATEADD(Day, -1, DATEADD(Month, 1, Cast(CAST(Month(@OrigDate) as varchar) + '/1/' + CAST((Year(@OrigDate)+1) as varchar) as datetime)))
```

Step 1: Create a new date in the same month, next year, but on the 1st.

Step 2: Adds one month

Step 3: Subtracts one day

Comment: EDIT: dang, it doesn't add a year, I've updated my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,'2012-01-12')), DATEADD(m,13,'2012-01-12')) expirationDate
```

Outputs

2013-01-31 00:00:00.000